# PHP / Mysql special character inserts being truncated

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo

I am having an issue with inserting words with  special characters into my database. The word seems to get truncated at the special character.

I am using MySQL 5.1.41 the collation on my database is utf8_general_ci. I am using PDO to facilitate database interaction.

Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
//$db is a PDO object
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
//word with a special character 
$word = "pépite";
$sql = "INSERT INTO keyword(key_name) VALUES(?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($word));
```

When this executes I just get "p" in my database, it seems the character é and everything after it is truncated. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. If anyone could suggest what I am doing incorrectly it would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you perhaps using the `mysqli` client for PHP instead of the `mysql` one?

Comment: Is it just cutting it off at one character every time, or just storing everything up to the special character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$word = utf8_encode('pépite');
$sql = "INSERT INTO keyword(key_name) VALUES(?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($word));
```

[utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-encode.php) | [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.utf8-decode.php)

Comment: Yes, this did it thanks much. Could you tell me why I needed to encode as utf8, wasn't the string already utf8?

Comment: No, you have to encode the special characters like ñáéíóú... with that function. I'm from Argentina (my native language it's spanish) so I've this problem allways :) For example é = Ã© in UTF8.